# Minimize chat input area − remove links and site logo, no auto width

Tags: script, chat, stylish

Chat input area background takes up all the horizontal space it can get. It's time to stop this greedy nonsense! This script removes the `width:auto` rule and hides the site's logo and links at the right side of the input area:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Minimize chat input area − remove links and site logo, no auto width
// @namespace   chat.se
// @match        *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1.0.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = css;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('#footer-legal, #footer-logo {display: none !important;} #input-area {   width: initial !important; }');
```

Or this Stylish script:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com"), domain("chat.stackoverflow.com"), domain("chat.meta.stackexchange.com")
{
  #footer-legal, #footer-logo {display: none !important;}  
  #input-area { width: initial !important; }
}
```